# How to find the minimum $q$ satisfying $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{p}{q}<\frac{c}{d}$

Tags: number-theory

Given four positive integers $a,b,c,d$($\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$), how to find the minimum positive integer $q$  satisfying $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{p}{q}<\frac{c}{d}$(integer p is not given)?

Comment: $ \frac{pd}{c} \leq q \leq \frac{pb}{a} $

Comment: @Macavity It isn't specified whether $p$ is integer as well or not.

Comment: @hjpotter92: The question wouldn't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: If $\lceil \frac{a}b \rceil < \lceil \frac{c}d \rceil$, obviously $q=1$. Else find the smallest $p$ s.t. $(pd/c, pb/a)$ contains an integer. $q$ is that integer.

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake, it should be < instead of $\leq$ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a positive integer $n$ satisfying $\frac{a}{b}<n<\frac{c}{d}$, so the answer is $1$.
Otherwise the problem can be converted into $0\leq\frac{a\ mod\ b}{b}<\frac{p}{q}<\frac{c\ mod\ d}{d}<1$.
When we get the minimum $q$, $p$ can also be minimum, then the problem can be converted into $\frac{d}{c\ mod\ d}<\frac{q}{p}<\frac{b}{a\ mod\ b}$.
This loop is similar to Euclidean algorithm, we can get the answer in O(log max{b,d})